# Create Array to validate duplicate CPF in a repeat loop in PHP

Tags: php

My main goal is to `import` data from an `Excel spreadsheet` into `Mysql using PHP`.

I completed this goal and now I can import all the columns from Excel to the respective database tables!

My next goal is to do some kind of `validation`!

For example!

Validate that the same `CPF exists for two different customers`.

Below is an example of the Excel spreadsheet !!

**CPF is the unique identification document of each Brazilian citizen**

[image]

Below is an example of the function that results in the plan excel column and row data

```
private function import_file($file)
    {
        $path   = $file;
        $object = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);

        foreach($object->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
        {
            $highestRow    = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
            $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();

            $person_array_testing = [];
            for($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++)
            {
                # array testing
                $cpf_cnpj = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue();
                $name     = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue();
                $contract = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue();
                $invoice  = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getValue();
                $document = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, $row)->getValue();
                $value    = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5, $row)->getValue();
                $expiry   = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6, $row)->getValue();
                $address  = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(7, $row)->getValue();
                $phone    = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(8, $row)->getValue();
                $email    = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(9, $row)->getValue();

                // print 1
                // pr($cpf_cnpj);
                // pr($name);

                if( ! empty($cpf_cnpj))
                {
                    $keys = [$cpf_cnpj];
                    $new_array = array_fill_keys($keys, $name);
                    // print 2
                    pr($new_array); 
                }                
                # array testing
            }
        }
    }
```

My idea to validate duplicate CPF was to create an array, using the CPF as the key and the customer's name as the value; then it would validate if the array key is repeated and, if so, it would return false and interrupt the import.

I believe that, in the case of a duplicate CPF, the expected array was this;

```
[
    '11111111177' => 'MARIA DE LOURDES CAETANO',
    '11111111177' => 'ADRIENE FARIA MARTINS CONRADO DOS SANTOS'
]
```

**Update**
`I don't think it would work because an array cannot have repeated keys`

Here are images of how to return, using or print_r from PHP
print 1 and 2, as it is in the function code, respectively
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea for the validation is correct, but you are failing to implement it.

You can try something like this:

```php
$validationArray = [];
if (!empty($cpf_cnpj)) {
    if (array_key_exists($cpf_cnpj, $validationArray) {
        return false;
    }

    $validationArray[$cpf_cnpj] = $name;
}
```

Or, if you don't want to interrupt the processing at each duplication, you can store the duplications in a different array and deal with them after importing:

```php
$validationArray = [];
$duplicationsArray = [];
if (!empty($cpf_cnpj)) {
    if (array_key_exists($cpf_cnpj, $validationArray) {
        $duplicationsArray[$cpf_cnpj] = $name;
    } else {
        $validationArray[$cpf_cnpj] = $name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, my return is error: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer

Comment: The error message is very clear: the variable `$cpf_cnpj` you are passing to the function does not contain a string. Are you doing something to `$cpf_cnpj` after getting it from the spreadsheet and before you do the validation?

Comment: I changed the data type of the variable `cpf_cnpj` to string and got the result, but moved the variables validationArray and duplicationArray out of the loop. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are right. Array does not contain same key. But you can use Multi-dimension array to short this problem.

> But as you said, export data in database. So you cannot use `CPF` key as a primary key or unique key.